# How do I call exported functions in NodeJS? Which can be nested?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js

This is my function inside `app.js` which I am exporting:

```
var app = {
  start: function() {
    //sample function
    exports.msgReceived = function() {
      return "Tomorrow 8pm near city hall";
    }
  }
}
module.exports = app;
```

I have a file called `messages.js` where I want to call `start` function and also `msgReceived` function:

```
let subscriber = require('app');

it('server gets connected', function(done) {
  subscriber.start(); // working
  subscriber.msgReceived(); // not working
  done();
});
```

How I can do that?

Because with `var` keyword I can only access `start` function. My code editor IntelliSense doesn't point to the `msgReceived` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, which sets the new function on the app object after running `start()`.

```
var app = {
  start: function() {
    //sample function
    this.msgReceived = function() { // `this` refers to `app`
      return "Tomorrow 8pm near city hall";
    }
  }
}
module.exports = app;
```

If you want intellisense to work you'll probably have to include

```
var app = {
  start : ...,
  msgReceived: null // or undefined... or anything.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
var app = {
  start: function() {
    //sample function
    let msgReceived = function() {
      return "Tomorrow 8pm near city hall";
    };
    return {msgReceived: msgReceived};
  }
}
module.exports = app;
```

.

```
let subscriber = require('app');

it('server gets connected', function(done) {
  let start = subscriber.start(); // working
  let msg = start.msgReceived(); // should work
  done();
});
```